# Dynamic 3d formula excel

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a workbook that has multiple sheets.
Each sheet is labeled with a Date code. 20201129, 20201128, 20201127

I have a formula on the first Sheet "total" `=sum('20201129:20201127'!A1)`. This works.
When I add a new data sheet called 20201130 to the left of 20201129, I would like to have the formula update to `=sum('20201130:20201127'!A1).`
Unfortunately, I cant find anything like `=sum(sheet(2):'20201127'!A1)` that would dynamically add the new second sheet (or last sheet if I add to the end)
I know I could add the new sheet to the right of the 2nd sheet and that is what I am doing but it isn't as elegant. I am trying to avoid a hidden sheet (also for elegance)

Comment: I think you may need to use VBA for this. You can create a [custom function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f) that gets the name of the [first sheet](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/select-first-sheet-of-workbook.68941/) and then use the [`INDIRECT`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) function.

Comment: Thanks,  I was trying to do this without custom functions or VBA as I wanted it to work for others who may freak out with having to allow something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a blank worksheet called *alpha* and put it **before** all your data sheets.  Create another blank worksheet called *omega* and put it **after** all your data sheets.

Your formula becomes:

```
=sum('alpha:omega'!A1)
```

Whenever you add another worksheet, just place it between your last data sheet and *omega*;
that way the `SUM()` will automatically include it.

Comment: I think this will be my goto option. I was trying to see if I could avoid the blank hidden sheets, but sometimes Function is more important than beauty